# DS18B20 doesn't work with pinMode for other devices

Tags: arduino-nano, ds18b20

i do some project. There is DS18B20, 3 mosfet modules, 1 relay, display 1602, buzzer... I built it on bread board, everything worked.
Now i soldered it: arduino works, display works but DS18B20 doesn't return temperature.

I tried to solder thermometer over again - no result.
Then i glanced at my sketch and tried to remove some code in loop and setup. I understood that DS18B20 works only if in setup function no `pinMode(...)` for other modules. It's odd!

This is part of my code:

```
#include <EncButton.h>     // For buttons
#include <microDS18B20.h>  // For thermometer DS18b20
#include <EEPROM.h>        // For EEPROM memory to save settings
#include <ezBuzzer.h>      // For buzzer
#include "Screen.h"

/* --- PINS --- */
#define kettle_relay_pin 4     // Relay of kettle
#define mixer_pin 5            // Mixer pin
#define termometer_pin A2      // Termometer pin
#define hot_pump_pin A0        // Hot water
#define sugar_dispenser_pin A1 // Sugar dispenser
#define buzzer_pin 9           // Buzzer pin

#define l_button_pin 11      // Left button
#define r_button_pin 12      // Right button
#define potent_pin A3        // Potentiometer pin for set int values
/* --- PINS --- */

#define INIT_ADDR 1023  // EEPROM addres for init key
#define INIT_KEY 1      // EEPROM init key

/* --- Initialize objects --- */
// Connect thermometer DS18b20
MicroDS18B20<termometer_pin> ds; 

ezBuzzer buzzer(buzzer_pin); // create ezBuzzer object that attach to a pin;

// Buttons
EncButton<EB_TICK, l_button_pin> l_button; 
EncButton<EB_TICK, r_button_pin> r_button; 

// LCD Display
#define _LCD_TYPE 1
#include <LCD_1602_RUS_ALL.h>
LCD_1602_RUS lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
Screen screen(&lcd); // Create screen object instance for convient work with lcd display
/* --- Initialize objects --- */

/* --- Initial values --- */
enum modes {
  // ...
};
modes currentMode = normalMode;

// Default settings
struct Settings{
   //...
} settings;

// Current values
int current_temp = 25; // Current temperature
// ...
/* --- Initial values --- */

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Buttons and potentiometer
    r_button.setButtonLevel(HIGH);
    l_button.setButtonLevel(HIGH);
    pinMode(potent_pin, INPUT);

    // Kettle
    pinMode(kettle_relay_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(kettle_relay_pin, LOW);
    
    // Pump
    pinMode(hot_pump_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(hot_pump_pin, LOW);

    // Mixer
    pinMode(mixer_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(mixer_pin, LOW);

    // Sugar dispenser motor
    pinMode(sugar_dispenser_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(sugar_dispenser_pin, LOW);

    // Buzzer
    pinMode(buzzer_pin, OUTPUT);

    // Init EEPROM
    if (EEPROM.read(INIT_ADDR) != INIT_KEY) {
        // EEPROM haven't been initialized yet
        EEPROM.write(INIT_ADDR, INIT_KEY); // Write init key
        EEPROM.put(0, settings); // Set default data
    }

    // Read settings and apply it
    EEPROM.get(0, settings);
    tea_temp = settings.tea_temp_default;       
    sugar_count = settings.sugar_count_default; 
    settings.mixer_time = 15 * 1000;

    // Init display
    screen.init();
}

unsigned long screenUpdateTimer = 0;

void loop() {
  buzzer.loop();
  
  l_button.tick();
  r_button.tick();

  creen.render(); // Always render information on display

  Serial.println(ds.online()); // TRUE

  // For ds18b20 tests
  ds.requestTemp();
  delay(1000);
  if (ds.readTemp()) Serial.println(ds.getTemp());
  else Serial.println("error");
    
  menuControl();
}
```

What's problem?

If i comment all `pinMode and digitalWrite` code, `ds.readTemp` works, else it's error.

**UPDATE #1**
I figured out that if i use ports A0 and A1, i get message "error" for this sketch:

```
#include <microDS18B20.h>
MicroDS18B20<A2> sensor;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  sensor.requestTemp();
  
  delay(1000);
  
  if (sensor.readTemp()) Serial.println(sensor.getTemp());
  else Serial.println("error");
}
```

And more. I get this message "error" every time without any connected modules. After some connects and disconnects of mosfet module to pins A0, A1, D5, D6. No temperature at all!
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update #2**
I think it's died.

My main sketch (it worked yesterday) now doesn't work at all. But then i try some reboots and it works but not properly...
So, if it works, i can see my menu on display but it's ierogliphs sometimes. also sometimes buttons stop to work...

Is aruino dead?
[image]

Comment: This doesn't really match your problem description, but it is a problem, I think. `LCD_1602_RUS lcd(0x27, 16, 2);`  `16` is another name for `A2` on the atmega328p/atmega168p Nano. Half expect you just typo'd it. Maybe you wired to 6? No diagram so, no way to know.

Comment: No, 1602 must be connected to A4, A5. And it worked for bread board

Comment: Now i figured out one more thing. If i connect mosfet module to A0 or to A1 pin, DS18B20 show error... IDK how it works...

Comment: i tried disconnect 1602 as well, no result

Comment: Include all this stuff you're figuring out [in your question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/90799/edit). Add a diagram. Remove any unnecessary stuff. If you can create the same problem without a 1602 display involved, remove it it from both your test setup and the question.

Comment: it looks like something is mis-wired

Comment: Welcome! Posting an annotated schematic, not a frizzy picture would go a long way in us helping you. Links to "Technical" information on the  hardware devices will also help.